# How does $-\frac1Z\sum_i\frac{\partial E}{\partial H}\exp(-\beta E_i)$ become $\frac1Z\frac1\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial H}\sum_i\exp(-\beta E_i)$?

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand how this manipulation was done :

$$-\frac{1}{Z} \sum_{i} \frac{\partial E}{\partial H} \exp \left(-\beta E_{i}\right) =\frac{1}{Z} \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial H} \sum_{i} \exp \left(-\beta E_{i}\right)$$

I can't see how the derivative was treated in order to obtain this result. Can someone show me explicitly how this was done?

I can see there must have been a partial derivative with respect to $E$ to get the $-\frac{1}{\beta}$ term but can't see how this fits in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should see this equation from right hand side to left hand side. It is easier to understand.

As following,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial H} \exp(-\beta E_i) = \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial H}\frac{\partial}{\partial E_i}\exp(-\beta E_i) = -\beta \exp(-\beta E_i)\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial H}$$

Comment: Thanks makes sense now!